# Estoy aprendiendo recursividad pero no imprime lo que le pido

Tags: java

Hola estoy haciendo un método con recursividad que imprima números del 1 al 5 como si fuera un ciclo pero no logro hacer que imprima los números esto es lo que hice:

```
public class Recursividad {

    public void Imprimir(int x) {
        if (x >= 5) {

            System.out.print(x + " ");

            Imprimir(x + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tienes en el if(x>=5) prueba cambiandolo a if(x<=5)

Answer (score -3):

Sabiendo la cantidad de veces que vas a recorrer el bucle, lo mejor sería que usaras un FOR o un WHILE. Con un for sería algo así:

```
public class recursividad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("x: " + (i +1));

        }
    }
}
```

Con un DO WHILE, que es la otra manera, sería algo así:

```
public class recursividad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int j = 0;
        do {

            System.out.println("y: " + (j +1));
            j = j + 1;

        } while (j <5);`introducir el código aquí`

    }
}
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Dijo que es un ejercicio de recursion, su respuesta no lo usa.